# Display the id of an object in many to many relation in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model(VariationPrice) in my Django app which has many to many relation with other model(Variation). Under Django Admin VariationPrice, one sees the variations field with many Variations inside it. Is it possible to display the Variation id (Variation.id) along with the Variation name in many to many field of django admin?

```
class VariationPrice(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variations = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, blank=True)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `VariantionPrice` have a `ForeignKey` to a `Variation` (only)? How is the `Variation` modeled towards a `Product`? Perhaps you do not even need a `VariationPrice` model at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the M2M object is rendered by it's `__str__()`  method. So the easiest way to achieve this is to simply add the ID to your str method of the Variation model:

```py
class Variation(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}-{self.id}"
```